How to get angular/google-map reference in component the right way
I use @angular/google-maps": "^17.3.5" and angular "^17.3.5"
I try to get a reference to my google-map
  <google-map #map mapId="map" height="100%" width="100%" [options]="options"</google-map>

from my component. However, @ViewChild(GoogleMap) map!: GoogleMap; does not seem to work. When I try to use it in ngAfterViewInit():
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    this.map.googleMap!.fitBounds({
      north: 43.516034,
      south: 43.423021,
      east: 5.471529,
      west: 5.456153,
    });
  }

I get:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'googleMap')

Using the mapInitialized seems to work, however, then I only get a google.map.Map and not the GoogleMap. I am not sure if this is a disadvantage in some way.
  <google-map #map (mapInitialized)="initMap($event)" mapId="map" height="100%" width="100%" [options]="options"></google-map>`

component:
map!: google.maps.Map


initMap(map: google.maps.Map) {
    this.map = map;
    this.initAdvancedMarkers()
  }

  async initAdvancedMarkers() {

    const {AdvancedMarkerElement} = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker") as google.maps.MarkerLibrary;

    let markers = [
      {
        lat: 43.516034,
        lng: 5.471529,
      },
      {
        lat: 43.523021,
        lng: 5.456153,
      },
      {
        lat: 43.423021,
        lng: 5.456153,
      },
    ];

    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Set markers and fit bounds to show all markers
    markers.forEach((marker: any) => {
      new AdvancedMarkerElement({
        map: this.map,
        position: marker
      });
      bounds.extend(
        new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng)
      );
    });

    this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }

I could not found a proper example doing this with the current version of google-maps, so any hint in the right direction would be appreciated.

Issue not reproducible, make sure you do not have the google maps element inside an @if or *ngIf that might block you from accessing it!
Else you can try toggling the static flag and check if it solves your issue!
@ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: true }) map!: GoogleMap;
// or
@ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: false }) map!: GoogleMap;

working stackblitz where view child is coming properly, below!
FULL CODE:
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { GoogleMap } from '@angular/google-maps';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [GoogleMap],
  template: `
    <!-- google-maps-demo.component.html -->
<google-map 
  height="400px"
  width="750px"
  [center]="center"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  (mapClick)="moveMap($event)"
  (mapMousemove)="move($event)" />

<div>Latitude: {{display?.lat}}</div>
<div>Longitude: {{display?.lng}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: true }) map!: GoogleMap;
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral = { lat: 24, lng: 12 };
  zoom = 4;
  display!: google.maps.LatLngLiteral | undefined;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.map);
    this.map!.fitBounds({ // <- changed here!
      north: 43.516034,
      south: 43.423021,
      east: 5.471529,
      west: 5.456153,
    });
  }

  moveMap(event: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) {
    this.center = <google.maps.LatLngLiteral>event.latLng?.toJSON();
  }

  move(event: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) {
    this.display = event.latLng?.toJSON();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for the fast answer. I created a new component for testing with only your code and I see the log of this.map in my console. However, I also get the error: core.mjs:6531 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fitBounds') at MapsTestComponent.ngAfterViewInit. Any ideas?  Best, Chris

@Christian try replicating the issue in the stackblitz and share back!

When I open your stackblitz via the "open preview in new tab" I see the same error as I have locally in the browser console

@Christian updated my answer, but the error mentioned in the question is not reproducible!

Yes I adjusted my code so that it matches yours, but I still get the error (which I also see in your stackblitz example, in my browsers console) aswell as locally:
chunk-P24TEMHF.js?v=ee851d03:6861 ERROR Error: Cannot access Google Map information before the API has been initialized. Please wait for the API to load before trying to interact with it.
Using the map initialized event seems to work.

@Christian can you check the index.html in the stackblitz, we need to include the API_KEY , you can refer getting started I installed using ng add @angular/google-maps

yes I included my API_KEY locally, this does not change the error I mentioned. For me it seems that its a timing issue, meaning in ngAfterViewInit the map is not yet fully initialized. When I use the google maps mapInitialized callback it seems to work. Do you get the error only when using no api key?

@Christian I do not get any error, I always get the viewchild value, maybe mapInitialized is the correct way, raise a github issue to check this scenario on their official page, if its not mentioned in the DOCS!
